# platform.linux_distribution() output for all major distros

Tags: linux, python-3.x

```
if [DISTRO,VERS,ARCH] = platform.linux_distribution()
```

I just need to know what DISTRO will be for diferent distros. I'm running arch so of course I have that. I also have opensuse. I need the output for ubuntu/debian, fedora, RHEL,sorcerer linux, slackware, gentoo and any others you can think of.

I have no way to install other distros to test this without wiping my arch install (running on 32GB flash drive).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `platform.py` source code:

```
_supported_dists = (
    'SuSE', 'debian', 'fedora', 'redhat', 'centos',
    'mandrake', 'mandriva', 'rocks', 'slackware', 'yellowdog', 'gentoo',
    'UnitedLinux', 'turbolinux', 'arch', 'mageia')
```

Note that you're almost always better off checking for features/programs/libraries that you need, instead of for the platform.

Perhaps the Python maintainers thought the same thing, because `linux_distribution()` is [deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.linux_distribution) in Python 3.5 onwards and will be removed in Python 3.7.

Comment: Thanks. I need it to make a front-end for their various package managers for my shell program. i'm pretty much basing it off of the latest versions of the distros.

Comment: p.s. and i thought it was platform.dist() that was deprecated?

Comment: how would i go about checking for features/programs/libraries?

Comment: If you want to e.g. offer a front-end for `apt`, just check whether `apt` is present on the system. That's both simpler and more robust than checking whether the system is `debian`, because many other distros also use `apt`.